# Different base64 encoding for same Image

Tags: c++, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I need to convert `base64 to opencv::mat` file. So I took a set of 10 frames from a video and appended `base64(A)`(using `base64.b64encode` in python).

After that, I used the code from [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html) to convert that base64 to Mat. Images looked fine.

But they have larger file size than the original images, plus when I encoded these final images to `base64(B)`(using `base64.b64encode` in python), the encoded base64 is different from original `base64(A)`. I can't understand why? This is also affecting the output of my application that is using the `cv::mat` output.

For `base64 to Mat` I am using code from [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html)(asposted above).

**Edited**: Following is my python script to convert set of `jpeg to base64` (.txt)

```
 def img2txt(file_directory):    
        imageFiles = glob.glob(file_directory+"/*.jpg")
        imageFiles.sort()
        fileWrite='base64encoding.txt'
        #print fileWrite
        for i in range(0,len(imageFiles)):
            image = open(imageFiles[i],'rb')
            image_read = image.read()
            image_64_encode = base64.b64encode(image_read)
            with open (fileWrite, 'a') as f: 
                f.writelines(image_64_encode+'\n')
```

**base64decode function** : from [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html)

```
static const std::string base64_chars =
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"0123456789+/";


static inline bool is_base64(unsigned char c) {
    return (isalnum(c) || (c == '+') || (c == '/'));
}

std::string base64_decode(std::string const& encoded_string) {
    int in_len = encoded_string.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int in_ = 0;
    unsigned char char_array_4[4], char_array_3[3];
    std::string ret;

    while (in_len-- && (encoded_string[in_] != '=') && is_base64(encoded_string[in_])) {
        char_array_4[i++] = encoded_string[in_]; in_++;
        if (i == 4) {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                char_array_4[i] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[i]);

            char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
            char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
            char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

            for (i = 0; (i < 3); i++)
                ret += char_array_3[i];
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i) {
        /*for (j = i; j < 4; j++)
            char_array_4[j] = 0;*/

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            char_array_4[j] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[j]);

        char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
        //char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

        for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++) 
            ret += char_array_3[j];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**C++ Main function**:

```
int main()
{  
  ifstream in("TestBase64.txt");
  if(!in) {
    cout << "Cannot open input file.\n";
    return 1;
    }
    int i=0;
    string encoded_string;
    while (getline(in, encoded_string)) 
    {
        string decoded_string = base64_decode(encoded_string);
        vector<uchar> data(decoded_string.begin(), decoded_string.end());
        cv::imwrite("/Frames_from_B_to_Mat/Frames_from_B_to_Mat"+b+".jpg");
        i++; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you load an image and save it again, it may be that it is saved with different algorithms/compression... then it can be bigger. If it is a lossy method like jpg, it will differ when you save it and the bas64 encoding will change. Take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216333/opencv-imread-imwrite-increases-the-size-of-png/12216875#12216875) which asks about the same problem (change in size)

Comment: @api55  I am using the Mat file as an input to my c++ application (not writing the image and then reading), and  I have compared the `Mat` file too for original initial image and the final image (orig image -> b64 -> mat -> final image), and they appear to be different. How can I make both mat file same in c++? Is there any problem with the b64 to mat decoding in this case ?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. What are you passing as input in both cases? in python is it the numpy array directly (cv::Mat in python are numpy arrays) ? In C++ you pass the received data as a string directly? or you parse it/cast it some other way? what is the dtype of the image in python? do you copy each in c++ each char of the decoded string as a number? or copy it directly in the data member? It will be good if you can edit and add some code to your question, to understand where could it go wrong.

Comment: @api55 Just to make it clear, firstly I am taking an Image (a jpeg), encode it in base64 (.txt) in python. In c++ I am using this base64(.txt) to get the corresponding cv:Mat which will act as input to my c++ application. PS: I have added my python script for jpeg to base64

Comment: the python script looks as I expected, can you add the C++ side? maybe the error is there. Maybe it is better to try with a small scale proof of concept, e.g. a 3x3 mat, this way you can put the toy example here and is easier to understand what could be going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line:

```
vector<uchar> data(decoded_string.begin(), decoded_string.end());
```

you are presumably holding the JPEG-encoded representation of one image in `data`. So you may as well just write this to a binary file, rather than use `cv::imwrite()` which is for writing a Mat to a file.

If, for some inexplicable reason, you want to use `cv::imwrite()`, you need to pass it a `Mat`. So you would end up decoding the JPEG representation to a Mat and then encoding to JPEG and writing - which seems silly:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imdecode(data, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::imwrite('result.jpg',img);
```

**TLDR;**

What I'm saying is that your data is already JPEG-encoded, you read it from a JPEG file.

Comment: `cv::Mat img = cv::imdecode(data, cv::IMREAD_COLOR); `

Comment: Yes, that's better. Thank you.

Comment: @Silencer金 Thanks a lot.