# Why is there a difference in file size when I save an image after loading it in python

Tags: python, opencv, png, image-compression

I loaded a PNG image in python and saved it back using cv2 in python, but I am getting a huge file size difference. Is there a way to get compression ratio as that of input?

```
print('input:',os.path.getsize("colorful_image.png"))
img = cv2.imread("colorful_image.png")
cv2.imwrite("output.png",img,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION),9])
print('output:',os.path.getsize('output.png'))
print('ratio:',os.path.getsize('output.png')/os.path.getsize("colorful_image.png"))
```

The output is as follows

```
input: 239868
output: 3475548
ratio: 14.489419180549302
```

Comment: Is it possible that your input is 8 bit paletted and your output isn't?

Comment: Kindly share the input and output images - use Google Drive or Dropbox if necessary. Thank you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/161ypZ50aqjMAe0Q6kqfICjYpcjoMxcdh?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

check it out by this post. `scipy.misc.imsave` save images correctly as an 8-bit image. [OpenCV - imread(), imwrite() increases the size of png?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216333/opencv-imread-imwrite-increases-the-size-of-png)

Comment: From scipy docs: imsave is deprecated! imsave is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imwrite instead.